# percentage of regular shapes surface area visible in 3d

Tags: geometry

inspired by [How many faces of a solid can one "see"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749730/339356)
at first I thought 3 faces of a cube and half a sphere seem opposite extremes both with 50% surface area visible. then I considered a regular triangular pyramid which can be seen with 75% area.  Is this the maximal visible percentage for a regular platonic solid?  what about a regular polyhedron?

Comment: _visible_ not visable.

Comment: This is sort of trivial because you can just hand check all of the possibilities.  For regular solids I believe that you are correct that a Triangular Pyramid has the largest visible surface area.  For non regular solids it is unbounded.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows, nice name. I'm not sure it's trivial for non platonic yet regular polyhedron such as https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%E2%80%93Poinsot_polyhedron

Comment: You're right that it wasn't as trivial as I thought.  I'm not 100% on the great stellated dodecahedra as it doesn't actually follow the rules I though it did.  I'll have to check but I'm pretty sure that it still doesn't even surpass 50%.

Comment: For all polyhedron which is centrally symmetric (i.e. invariant under reflection wrt to its centroid), you can see at most 50% of it. In fact, if the polyhedron is convex, you are observing it from infinity and not on any direction parallel to one of its faces,  exactly 50% of the faces are visible.

Comment: @achillehui so now we have an upper and lower bounds for symmetric polyhedron,are all polyhedron symmetric in the way you describe? I'm guessing no because I can see 75% of pryrimid

Comment: @shaihorowitz it is clear there are polyhedron that isn't symmetric. I just rule out the obvious.

Comment: @achillehui alright I just didn't understand how you used symmetry there. this is not my strong field.