# What is the highest percentage of surface area that can be seen at any given moment on a symmetrical object?

Tags: geometry

What is the highest percentage of surface area that can be seen at any given moment on a symmetrical object?

On a sphere its 50% right? (or close to it)

On a four-sided pyramid viewed from one of its points it would be 75%?

Can you get any higher?

Comment: What do you mean by symmetrical? The sphere has more symmetries than the tetrahedron.

Comment: I wonder about higher dimensional spheres. Does the ratio stay 50%?

Comment: Oddly enough, this question is basically the same as [this from a few years back](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1796093/26369).

Answer (score 2):

If a pyramid with a regular polygon base is symmetric enough for you it can be as close to $100\%$ as you like.  Just make the altitude huge compared to the side of the base and look from above the point.  You will see all the surface except the base.

Comment: If we regard "symmetric enough" as condition that isometry group acts irreducibly, then question becomes quite interesting.

Comment: I thought about that aswell, and that is definetley one way to solve it. In the end i decided that such a shape wasn't symmetrical enough for me. Then again, what interessed me about the question was the open nature of it and i think there may be many ways to approach it.